# Relative mouse position to clicked element

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a short question.

I'm using the FooBox plugin on my Wordpress site, accompanied by FooGallery. Now I want to add a little tweak with javascript.

When I  click on an image, the FooBox will show up, with arrows to the left and right. I want to add the same functionality to the image itself, so when you click the left side of the image it will go back in gallery, and if you click the right, it will go to the next image.

I've already know the answer in jQuery, but now i need a pure JS solution. Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have the element using

```
var elem = document.getElementById('yourId')
```

or

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('yourClass')[0]
```

or whatever

you may then add a handler to the `onclick` event

eg

```
elem.onclick = function(e){
  console.log(e)
}
```

log:

> click clientX=480, clientY=63

Comment: Thanks, now i just need to compare these values to the half of the relative width.